# if an a link contain something in the href change the href to this

Tags: jquery, href, javascript

i want to check if the href contains 'coming-soon' if it does change the href to go to my products page:

```
$('a[href$="coming-soon"]').attr('href', '/products.aspx');
```

cant work this out.

Answer (score 4):

[`$=` is "attribute-ends-with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), use [`*=` for "attribute contains"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), like this:

```
$('a[href*="coming-soon"]').attr('href', '/products.aspx');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[href*='coming-soon']").attr('href', '/products.aspx');
});
```

[Try it here!](http://jsfiddle.net/sEp6t/)

Answer (score 0):

`$=` means "ends with".  You want to find links that *contain* (anywhere in the URL) coming-soon? Try `*=` instead of `$=`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is currently any anchor tag whose `href` **ends with** `coming-soon`. The contains selector is `*=`:

```
$('a[href*="coming-soon"]').attr('href', '/products.aspx');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

If this isn't the problem, ensure the code is ran when the DOM is loaded; by wrapping the code in the `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*="coming-soon"]').attr('href', '/products.aspx');
});
```